# Complicated Logic Proof involving Tautology and Law of Excluded Middle

Tags: logic

I'm having great difficulty solving the following problem, and even figuring out where to start with the proof.
$$
\neg A\lor\neg(\neg B\land(\neg A\lor B))
$$
Please see the following examples of how to do proofs, I would appreciate it if you could attempt to give me guidance using the tools and the line numbers that it cites similar to those below:

***This is a sample proof:***

[image: This is a sample proof]

***This is another sample proof (law of excluded middles):***

[image]

Comment: What logic are you using ?

Comment: @chandok, This is First order logic.  And it is about formal proofs and boolean logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all the statement is true (checking truth values for $A$ and $B$), even though ive now given two incorrect answers... here we go again!

$\begin{align}
& \neg A \lor \neg (\neg B \land (\neg A \lor B))\\
& =\neg A \lor \neg [(\neg B \land \neg A) \lor (\neg B \land B)]\\
& =\neg A \lor \neg [(\neg B \land \neg A) \lor FALSE]\\
& =\neg A \lor \neg(\neg B\land\neg A)\\
& =\neg A\lor(B\lor A) \text{ using } \neg(X\land Y)=\neg X\lor\neg Y\\
& =TRUE
\end{align}$

formalize this in whatever system youre using, you might have to prove a few things beforehand...

Comment: Could you please elaborate further.  I'm sorry, but I am having a very hard time comprehending your answer.  Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: How do you get $TRUE$ from $\lnot[(\lnot B\land\lnot A)\lor FALSE]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like assuming the negation would give you a contradiction:

use ~ for 'negation', and & for 'and'; then your negated assumption becomes:

A&(~B&(~A\/B))                     (Assumption)

From which you get:

~B&(~A\/B)                        (By & elimination)

I think you can show from here that your (negated) assumption leads to a contradiction, by arguing by cases, from ~A\/B, and showing neither case is possible.

Now, ~A\/B follows using a second & elimination. Show neither ~A nor B is possible
  from the premises in your negated statement. Then from ~A\/B and ~(~A) and ~B,
  a contradiction to your negated assumption follows.

Edit: this may be much simpler, tho yoyo's answer may be better than
   mine in that he gives a direct proof, and mine is by contradiction:

Assume the negation of your statement:

i)A& (~B&(~A\/B))

ii)Conclude A, by detachment.

iii)Conclude ~A by detachment inside of parenthesis.

iv)Negation of 'i)' follows by contradiction A&~A

Where detachment--more precisely, &-detachment-- is the rule that allows us to conclude either A, or B, from a statement A&B. To show it is a valid rule, you can either use a truth table to show it is a tautology/logical truth, derive it from the empty set of premises (this is the definition of theorem I am more familiar with), or,equivalently, show that the negation of either of :(A&B-->A) or of (A&B-->A), is a contradiction.For the second approach, assume A&B, and just conclude A (seems tautological, but it works; many of these arguments in sentence logic seem tautological anyway), or transform the implication A&B->A into the equivalent statement ~(A&B)\/A == ~A\/~B\/A== ~A\/A\/B==(~A\/A)\/B (I'm using here the result that A->B is truth-functionally equiv. to ~A\/B), which is a tautology.

Comment: What do you mean by detachment?

Comment: KerxPhilo: I mean that from an expression A&B, we can "detach" either A or B. More precisely, I mean

Comment: erxPhilo: I mean that from an expression A&B, we can "detach" either A or B. More precisely, that:            i) A&B->A , and                                                           ii)A&B-> B,                                                 In my proof, specifically, from A&(~B&(~A\/B), we can "detach" either the 'A' on the left, or the expression '(~B&(~A\/B))' to the right of the '&'.  Since we have another '&' in the parenthesis '(~B&(~A\/B))', we can detach either '~B'or '~A\ /B'

Comment: Sorry for the choppy formatting in the above comments, KerxPhilo. I edited my answer to incorporate everything into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "complicated" formula :

> $¬A∨¬(¬B∧(¬A∨B))$

can be re-written, due to the equivalence between $P \rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P \lor Q$, as :

> $A \rightarrow \lnot ((A \rightarrow B) \land \lnot B)$.

But $P \rightarrow Q$ is also equivalent to $\lnot (P \land \lnot Q)$; so the formula it is simply :

> > $A \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B)$.

Now, a *Natural Deduction* proof is quite easy :

*(1)* $A$ - assumed

*(2)* $A \rightarrow B$ --- assumed

*(3)* $B$ --- from (1) and (2) by $\rightarrow$-elimination

*(4)* $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B$ --- from (2) and (3) by $\rightarrow$-introduction

*(5)* $A \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B)$ --- from (1) and (4) by $\rightarrow$-introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof using a Fitch-style proof checker.

[image]

Assume the negation of what one is trying to prove on line 1 to attempt to derive a contradiction.

From lines 2 to 9, use De Morgan rule (DeM), conjunction elimination (∧E), double negative elimination (DNE) and disjunctive syllogism (DS) to simplify so one can arrive at two lines, 4 and 9, which are contradictory. That contradiction allows one to derive the goal on line 11 using indirect proof (IP).

Links to the proof checker and associated text are below.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf